# Blazor Wasm standalone publish to IIS

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly

to enable IIS compression I use web config from:
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#brotli-and-gzip-compression)

I publish (self-contained/browser-wasm) to IIS with web deploy and Visual Studio replaces every time web.config with the default version.
I tried to add web.config from docs in my project so it should be merged at publish time, but the file doesn't appear in output folder and in IIS website i have only wwwroot folder.

where am i wrong?
how to automatically publish the right web.config file?

Comment: Did you add the web.config in the root folder? If you use blazor client, there will not web.config in floder after publish it.

Comment: Bruce, yes I have it in publish folder, but not after adding web.config to project

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem:
[IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#standalone-deployment)

Section "Use a custom web.config"

Added to project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: After this publish work, but stop working in local from Visual Studio

Comment: Did you figure out how to have local keep working when adding web.config to root of project? Can no longer run locally in visual studio

Comment: @DanSoltesz No, I simply renamed it, and rename again before publish

Comment: Still the solution for .NET 6 WASM apps, though the docs don't mention it anymore. Running in IIS Express it breaks, but if you change to run as a stand-alone app then it works fine locally